# Framing a window directly through a post in post-and-beam construction?

Tags: framing, load-bearing

I have a single story home built on a concrete slab using post and beam construction. I have 4x4 posts spaced 5 feet apart along the exterior wall with 4x8 beams holding up a 4" tongue and groove roof with composite shingles.

[image]

I am considering the removal of the post and replacing it with a sufficient header and jack studs so that the window isn't bisected by the post.

I know having a professional engineer come and evaluate is my best option, but I am also considering over-speccing it if I can arrive at some kind of rough estimate for an appropriate header and supporting jack studs. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post and beam is so far from everyday construction techniques that use of anything but an engineer's analysis just seems wrong. The kings and jacks at the sides, and hte loads they support are totally different from conventional stick construction.

Comment: Move the window, leave the post alone. Or leave the window, and leave the post alone. You don't have enough headroom above that window opening to put in adequate framing to do anything else (courtesy my gut, which is not licensed to perform engineering in any political jurisdiction, but which is often correct anyway.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal Just saw your comment, while I was posting the answer below. I think I would trust your gut on this one - mine is in agreement.

Comment: You're removing a vertical support from the structure. What are the proposed jack studs sitting on that will reliably transfer the beam load into other vertical support posts? The wall framing is not a support structure in this construction and if those jack studs are merely planted on the floor plate without  a post **beneath** where each side contacts it, you're merely creating a cosmetic application that gives a facsimile of framed construction support without the support. Looks pretty...

Comment: Agree that the structural concerns above make changing things difficult. Have you considered 2 windows -- 1 per hole?

Comment: Thanks for the insight everyone. I didn't realize the degree to which the construction method makes this significantly less straightforward. I'm now less interested in avoiding an engineer's evaluation if I decide to proceed with my original plan.

Comment: I think the 2 window option is what I'll end up doing. I think my hope in asking this question was to see if there was any kind of obvious convention that is frequently done in cases like mine. It sounds like the uncommon nature of the construction pretty much requires a professional engineer if I don't want to be an idiot about it (which of course I don't). Thanks for all the input everyone. I'm disappointed, but am convinced that this is not the place to be improvising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the vertical post and finding some other way of supporting the roof beam will be complicated, specially since there is very little space between the window top and where the roof beam enters the wall. This is where you would need to insert a cross beam or similar to support the load from the roof. Needless to say, it will not be pretty and would probably still block a large part of your existing window.

Alternatively, you could consider moving the window. There seems to be sufficient space to the left of the photo. Although it would be a bit more work, no structural elements will be compromized, and most of the covering materials taken off to make space for the window could be re-used to fill up the gap on the other side.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I think you provided the answer I was really looking for: whether or not it was viable and if there would be a straightforward solution... for me it's sounding like the costs aren't going to be worth the benefits, so I think I'll just leave the structure alone.

Comment: @Wilco Wise decision! ;-)